# Cancel ONLY one task with CancellationToken

Tags: c#, task, producer-consumer

Lets assume that we have a Producer-Consumer pattern created with One Producing Task and 3 Consumer Tasks as follow:

```
        Task[] Consumer = new Task[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            Consumer[i] = Task.Run(() => DoWork(CancellationToken ct));
        }
```

the question is how can I ONLY cancel Task Consumer[2]? when a cancellationtoken is sent all the Consumers stop! I want to have the ability to cancel a single Consumer if needed.

Many thanks

Comment: You would need to make separate cancellation tokens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to cancel all the consumers independently, you need separate cancellation tokens - and thus separate cancellation token sources.

```
var consumers =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(_ => new CancellationTokenSource())
        .Select(cts => new { Task = Task.Run(() => DoWork(cts.Token)),
                             TokenSource = cts })
        .ToList();
```

That will gives you a `List<T>` where each element is the task and its corresponding `CancellationTokenSource`. So if you wanted to cancel `consumers[0].Task`, you'd call `consumers[0].TokenSource.Cancel()`.

Comment: @Gusman: I don't view it as an abuse of LINQ... the alternative would be a loop which is just projecting into a collection, which sounds like exactly the kind of thing LINQ is designed for :)

Comment: ok, maybe "abuse" is not the best word, maybe "extended use"? anyway, really clever

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you sir. Very helpful, it seems that `TrySetCanceled()` is not a method of `consumers[0].TokenSource`, but `Cancel()` is though.

Comment: @TimeMachine: You're right - I was getting confused with `TaskCompletionSource`. Will edit the answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon, could you please kindly advise how this can be achieved using a loop rather than LINQ?

Comment: @TimeMachine: Why would you not want use LINQ? Yes, you *could* create the list in a loop, but it would be me uglier code in my view. You should be able to manage it quite easily if you understand the existing answer - I suggest you try it yourself, and ask a new question showing where you're stuck if you have problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, I think the above code works if we initially know the number of tasks that are required (i.e 10). We declare them with their associated cancellation tokens. but what if we don't know the total number  of tasks at any time?

Comment: @TimeMachine: Then I don't know what the question looks like, basically. I answered the question you asked, where you started a fixed number of tasks. If you have a different question, you should ask it (as clearly as you can) in a different post.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree and my apologies, I have tried to outline what exactly I want to achieve here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816146/cancel-specific-task-using-cancellationtoken could you please kindly have a look?