# Cancel Specific Task using CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have the following Loop which may or may not create a series of tasks dynamically:

```
While(CreateNewTask == true)
{
 if(isWorkerFree() && isValidJob() && isExecutable())
 {
   CancellationTokenSource cs = new  CancellationTokenSource();
   var myTask = Task.Run(() => Execute(cs.token);
 }
}
```

Now since these tasks are created dynamically, how can I track them and cancel a specific task or send a cancellation token to a specific task? There may be 6-7 tasks running at any time, I need the functionality to know which ones are running and cancel a specific one.

Comment: How would you identify *which* one you want to cancel? And what's going to set `CreateNewTask` to false?

Comment: @JonSkeet The while loop is looking at a Queue, if there is a new task in the Queue, it sets the 'CreateNewTask' to true.  I want to have maximum of 7 tasks(workers) running at the same time. for each item in the queue we create a task, and execute the task. The task may take anything from few minutes to few hours to complete. So I want the capability of canceling a running task. now as you outlines I have two challenges: a) get a list of running tasks at any time, and b) cancel a specific one. I truly appropriate your help.

Comment: You still haven't said *how* you'd specify which one you want to cancel. It does sound like you should be looking at TPL Dataflow though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon, Ideally an admin will send a request through a service to cancel a task.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question - you're starting tasks, and you want to cancel one of them... how would you expect to know *which* task to cancel?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, now I know what you mean. I have implemented a `List<CustomRequest>`. The `CustomRequest` class contains a set of properties (ID, Status, etc) and a method called `Execute`. my code above will create a task `var myTask = Task.Run(() => CustomRequest.Execute(cs.token);`. Now, I would like to get the list of all the tasks with `CustomRequest.Status = "Running"` and cancel a task which is executing `CustomRequest.ID = 5`. I hope this clarifies my question and once again thank you.

Comment: Well it sounds like you probably want a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, TaskWrapper>` then, where the `TaskWrapper` has the `Task`, `CancellationTokenSource` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can track each such task using a DTO: `class Item { Task Task; CancellationTokenSource CTS; }`. Keep a list of those items. You can then cancel them at will.

Comment: @user2972161 A "data transfer object". A dumb class that only holds some fields. Not sure what you have in mind with the ActionBlock specifically.

Comment: I have an ActionBlock that can run up to 16 tasks concurrently, but I would like to be able to somehow attach a list of Cancellation tokens so that any of those 16 tasks could be cancelled.  The Action block is part of my TPL Dataflow pipeline.  There seems to be no examples of what I want to do, but I cannot be the first person to want to do this.

Comment: @user2972161 you can pass the CancellationToken into the action block together with the data you want to process. The code in that ActionBlock then needs to obey the CancellationToken and cancel itself.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**
I think that the TPL Dataflow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) is a better choice here but I will answer using the TPL

**Answer**
To limit the concurrency, what you need is a scheduler that limits concurrency. I suggest that you look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx and search for LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler.

The code below is a simple example of what you are trying to achieve.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod1()
    {
        var factoryCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var scheduler = new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler(maxDegreeOfParallelism: 7);
        var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(factoryCancellation.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler);

        var taskCancellation1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var taskCancellation2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token1 = taskCancellation1.Token;
        var token2 = taskCancellation2.Token;

        var myTask1 = taskFactory.StartNew(async () => await Execute(0, token1), token1).Unwrap();
        var myTask2 = taskFactory.StartNew(async () => await Execute(1, token2), token2).Unwrap();

        taskCancellation1.CancelAfter(500);

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(myTask1, myTask2);
        }
        catch
        {
            //ThrowIfCancellationRequested Exception
        }
    }

    private async Task Execute(int i, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Running Task {i} : Before Delay 1");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.WriteLine($"Running Task {i} : Before Delay 2");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Console.WriteLine($"Running Task {i} : Before Delay 3");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

This will generate the following log

```
QueueTask 1  WaitingToRun
QueueTask 2  WaitingToRun
TryExecuteTask Start 1  WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
TryExecuteTask Start 2  WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
Running Task 1 : Before Delay 1
Running Task 0 : Before Delay 1
TryExecuteTask End 2 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTask End 1 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 5 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 5 WaitingToRun IsCanceled False IsCompleted False IsFaulted False
QueueTask 5 System.Action WaitingToRun
TryExecuteTask Start 5 System.Action WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
Running Task 1 : Before Delay 2
TryExecuteTask End 5 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 6 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 6 WaitingToRun IsCanceled False IsCompleted False IsFaulted False
QueueTask 6 System.Action WaitingToRun
TryExecuteTask Start 6 System.Action WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 8 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 8 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTask End 6 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 12 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 12 WaitingToRun IsCanceled False IsCompleted False IsFaulted False
QueueTask 12 System.Action WaitingToRun
TryExecuteTask Start 12 System.Action WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
Running Task 1 : Before Delay 3
TryExecuteTask End 12 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 14 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 14 WaitingToRun IsCanceled False IsCompleted False IsFaulted False
QueueTask 14 System.Action WaitingToRun
TryExecuteTask Start 14 System.Action WaitingToRun CreationOptions None
TryExecuteTaskInline Start 16 taskWasPreviouslyQueued False
TryExecuteTaskInline End 16 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
TryExecuteTask End 14 RanToCompletion IsCanceled False IsCompleted True IsFaulted False
```

You can see that the Task 0 is cancelled as soon as possible and Task 1 continue to process. This example does not show but will never be more than 7 concurrent tasks.

Unfortunately the TAP pattern does not works with the AttachToParent option of the Scheduler, or this code could be even more clean. See: [TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent is not waiting for child task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150448/taskcreationoptions-attachedtoparent-is-not-waiting-for-child-task)

And to manage the CancellationTokens you can create a specific TaskFactory that allows something like this:

```
taskFactory.StartNew(0 , () => {...});
taskFactory.Cancel(0);
```

None of the TaskFactory methods are virtual so you will have to create overloaded method.