# CancellationToken Source - how to cancel a specific task

Tags: c#

*I saw this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816146/cancel-specific-task-using-cancellationtoken
But does not answer specifically*

**How do I cancel a specific Task , say Task 5?**

Given:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(i, token), token);

}

static void DoSomeWork(int taskNum, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // Do work here, checking and acting on ct.IsCancellationRequested where applicable, 
}


// Cancel Task #5  !!!!  How?
```

thx

Comment: What is the problem in using an `if()` statement and check for `taskNum`? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do and what you have already tried.

Comment: Store the `CancellationTokenSource` objects in a collection, that way you can cancel specific tasks if you so choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your specific code, note that my answer will need to be tailored to any different code, such as a dynamic amount of tasks, but here's what you do.

You store the `CancellationTokenSource` objects in a collection, that way you can cancel any specific task.

```
CancellationTokenSource ctss = new CancellationTokenSource[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ctss[i] = tokenSource;
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(i, token), token);
}

// Cancel Task #5  !!!!  How?
ctss[5].Cancel();
```

Comment: Thx.. how can I name the tokens, can cancel by name?

Comment: @Jon Put them in a `Dictionary<string, CancellationTokenSource>` maybe?